# Vue 2 vue-router 2 laravel 5.3 issue

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.3, vue-router

please help me with this error on console

> **router.map** is not function

I am using  **browserify** and  **laravel5.3**

here is my app.js code :

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js';
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');

import App from '../components/App.vue';
import Dashboard from '../components/Dashboard.vue';
import Home from '../components/Home.vue';
import Register from '../components/Register.vue';
import Signin from '../components/Signin.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter);


export var router = new VueRouter()

router.map({
    '/': {
        name: 'home',
        component: require('../components/Home.vue')
    },
    '/register': {
        name: 'register',
        component: Register
    }
})

router.start(App, '#app');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

vue-router 2.0, like Vue 2.0 has significant changes from v1.

In this specific case, routes are now declared differently:

```
new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/foo', component: Foo },
    { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
  ]
})
```

https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html

I *strongly* encourage you read up on what has changed in both.

Comment: Thank You very much